# what metrics to evaluate rank order results?

Tags: prediction, model-evaluations, performance, metric, ranking

I have searched on stackexchange and found a couple of topics like [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64707/calculating-rank-ordering-error-metric-for-implicit-recommendation) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159657/metrics-for-evaluating-ranking-algorithms) but they are not quite relevant to my problem (or at least I don't know how to make them relevant to my problem).

Anyway, say I have two sets of prediction results, as show by `df1` and `df2`.

```
y_truth = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
y_predicted_rank1 = [6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5]
y_predicted_rank2 = [4, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6, 10, 5]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tag': yy_truth, 'predicted_rank': y_predicted_rank1}).sort_values('predicted_rank')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'tag': yy_truth, 'predicted_rank': y_predicted_rank2}).sort_values('predicted_rank')

print(df1)

#   tag predicted_rank
#1  1   1
#3  1   2
#5  1   3
#7  1   4
#9  1   5
#0  0   6
#2  0   7
#4  0   8
#6  0   9
#8  0   10


print(df2)
#   tag predicted_rank
#1  1   1
#3  1   2
#5  1   3
#0  0   4
#9  1   5
#7  1   6
#2  0   7
#4  0   8
#6  0   9
#8  0   10
```

By looking at them, I know `df1` is better than `df2`, since in `df2`, a negative sample (zero) was predicted to have rank #4. So my question is,  what metric can be used here so that I can (mathematically) tell `df1` is better than `df2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing two rankings [Spearman's rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) is a good measure. It's probably worth a try, but since your gold truth appears to be binary I would think that [top-N accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95391/what-is-the-definition-of-top-n-accuracy) (or some variant of it) would be more appropriate (advantage: easy to interpret). You could also consider using the [Area Under the Curve (AUC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve), using the predicted rank as variable threshold (less intuitive to but doesn't require choosing any top N).